# Isolation Levels - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions, isolation-level

If I'm using

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

Do I need to wrap the query in a transaction

e.g.

```
BEGIN TRAN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SELECT * FROM
T1
COMMIT
```

Or can I just have a normal query?

Also, is there any benefit to including SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED and WITH (NOLOCK). I understand that one is for the table level and one is for the whole connection level. But is there any benefit to having both?

Such as:

```
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    SELECT * FROM
    T1 WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: Considering that your statement isn't doing any `DLL` or `DLM` changes, then then the need for a `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` is pointless; there's nothing to `COMMIT`.

Comment: Be aware that *every* query/DML statement runs in a transaction. But by default, SQL Server automatically commits the transaction for you. Also, using either of `READ UNCOMMITTED` or `WITH (NOLOCK)` is something that needs *careful consideration of the implications*. If you're just considering using them because someone told you that they were fast and/or took out minimal locks, realise that that advice may be factually correct but completely ignores the *purpose* of locking and isolation levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always we executes procedure of INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE transaction with READ COMMITTED ISOLATION LEVEL. If we need dirty data from any table then it helps. Because Transaction is defined with READ COMMITTED and table return dirty reads using WITH(NOLOCK) in JOIN Query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap **the query below** in a transaction:

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

Because even if wrapping **the query above** in a transaction as shown below, **isolation level** is still set on **session(connection) level** but not on **transaction level**:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
COMMIT
```

So, even if rollbacking **isolation level** as shown below, **isolation level** is not rollbacked so it's still `READ UNCOMMITTED` but not `READ COMMITTED`.

```sql
BEGIN TRAN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
ROLLBACK -- Isolation level is still "READ UNCOMMITTED" but not "READ COMMITTED"
```